# RoR How to set the root to show the latest entry in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have researched and seen a lot of ways of retrieving the latest entry in a model using something like `Post.order("created_at").last` but have been unsuccessful in making that the root for the webpage to land on.

Comment: That's not cool. Show us code that you have so far first and then someone will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the root to a custom action on the PostsController and have that handle it for you. For example:

*routes.rb*

```
root 'posts#show_latest'
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
def show_latest
  @post = Post.order("created_at").last
  render :show
end
```

Comment: Was looking for something like this. Is it OK that we're using a non-RESTful resource here, or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I don't see that this is non-RESTful ... it is doing a http GET on a resource as a simple lookup. There is no creation, deletion or modification of the resource.